# How to change this body manipulation with section manipulation in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, html, typescript, angular6

We are trying to change CSS id's based on time. The point is that currently, it manipulates the body. How can we change it into section manipulation?

**Angular part**

```
ngOnInit() {
this.run(1000, 10)
}
run(interval, frames) {
    var int = 1;

    function func() {
        document.body.id = "b"+int;
        int++;
        if(int === frames) { int = 1; }
    }

    var swap = window.setInterval(func, interval);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<section class='full-screen'>
...
...
</section>
```

there are different css snippets for #b1, #b2, #b3... since above code changes these ids during each time period. I assume something should be changed here:

```
document.body.id = "b"+int;
```

How move that function usage from body into above HTML section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a [*Template reference variable*](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-) in your template for the `section` tag:

   ```
   <section #section class='full-screen'>
      ...
      ...
   </section>
   ```
2. Add a `@ViewChild` decoratored variable in your component's ts file to get this element:

   ```
   @ViewChild('section', { read: ElementRef }) mySection: ElementRef;
   ```
3. Now you can use it like this in your component's ts file:

   ```
   ngOnInit() {
     this.run(1000, 10)
   }

   run(interval, frames) {
     var int = 1;

     function func() {
       this.mySection.nativeElement.id = "b"+int;
       int++;
       if(int === frames) { int = 1; }
     }

     var swap = window.setInterval(func.bind(this), interval);
   }
   ```

See this simple [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-child-view)

**UPDATE:**

Note that you're using `function func()`, this will cause you a scoping problem with using `this` as your component object. One way to fix this is by using `bind` function:

```
var swap = window.setInterval(func.bind(this), interval);
```

Updated the demo to show this in action.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will check it :)

Comment: It says nativeElement is undefined.

Comment: What can cause it?

Comment: I guess you did something wrong, take a closer look at the implementation, and the demo. make sure that your #name is equal to the @ViewChild('name'), and that the viewchild variable name is the one you're trying to reference as `this.name.nativeElement`

Comment: I copied your answer's code only inside component.ts and HTML. Checked once again. Everything is the same.

Comment: Now I understand why this is not working for you. this is a scope issue because of the `function func()...`, I'll update my answer to help you with that

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById("div_top1").setAttribute("id", "div_top2");

You can use this to change section id.

Comment: There is a section with class on which it should be implemented. 
<section class='full-screen'>  so what is div_top1 or ("id", "div_top2"); in your code?
It looks something else.

Comment: This is not a good solution in Angular, you shouldn't search the dom this way in Angular.

Comment: @benshabatnoam so how will the better solution be for Angular?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it thanks to angular viewChild feature

in your html:

```
<div #foo class="myClass"></div>
```

in your component ts file

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
// ....
export MyComponernt implement AfterViewInit {
    // ....
    @ViewChild('foo') foo: ElementRef;
    // ....
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        // this is how you manipulate element id properly thanks to angular viewChild feature
        this.foo.nativeElement.id = 'something';
    }
    // ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will test it.

Comment: The property of  nativeElement is undefined.